# How do I use Selenium in Python to select a date 3 days ahead of today?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath, automation

[image: Calendar Input]

Hey guys I'm trying to write a script to automatically book a slot in my gym 3 days after the current date as I tend to forget to book it and I'm kind of stuck trying to grab the date. I was thinking I could grab the current date and move 3 blocks to the right to book 3 days in advanced. I also tried using the datetime module and enter it into the textbox above the calendar but that doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime

PATH = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads/Selenium drivers/chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(#Login Website Link)

user = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
number = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
purpose = "XXXXXXXXXX"
dep = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

today = datetime.date.today()
bkDate = today + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
bkDate_new = bkDate.strftime("%a, %d-%m-%Y")
bkDateNum = bkDate.strftime("%d")

user_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("j_username")
user_textbox.send_keys(user)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("j_password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-button")
login_button.click()

driver.get("#Booking Website Link")

number_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("contact_no")
number_textbox.send_keys(number)

purpose_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("purpose")
purpose_textbox.send_keys(purpose)

slot1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/fieldset/form/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/label[7]/i")
slot1.click()

bkDate_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/[text() = '8']")
bkDate_input.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so well, but you need to understand the html structure for the calendar item.
While getting the current date, try to make 2 variables from there: month and the date that you want to select.
Now, you just need to explore the html code and create locators based on visible text and click on them. (for the month you will need to click on the dropdown first to have all options visible).

Comment: How would I do that though?